# Html does not display in 1/2 columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have product details in one column and the description in the other. I tried to change the margin of `review-box` and also `inner`.

Still the content does not fit:

[image]

Here is an example:

My goal is to have it look like the following:

[image]

Any suggestions why the `Lorem ipsum column` is  not near the product description?

I appreciate  your reply!

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happens because the sum of column width is more than 100%.

You can change the column width:

```
.su-column-size-1-2 {
  width: 46%;
}
```

Or use padding instead margin:

```
.su-row .su-column {
  padding: 0 0 0 4%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `<br>` tag given right after div tag.
that means 
your code is like this

`<div class="su-row"><br>`

change it to `<div class="su-row">`